# Crontab job with timeout

Tags: bash, cron, timeout

I have a crontab job that executes a .sh script hourly. This script navigates(cd...) to a directory and then launches a java program (java -jar).

If I want to make sure the java program doesn't run for longer than 30 minutes, where should I set the timeout? Should it be in the crontab or in the .sh script?

Comment: If it only runs Java, why don't you do the timeout in the Java itself? This will be helpful in case you would run the java in another context or even O/S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you put the timeout is situation dependent.  A metric I might use would be "What would most reduce the cognitive and maintenance burden on *the next person* (who might be me in a years time!)?"  Sometimes, the context of the situation dictates to use an argument to the cronjob program, other times it is better to use [`timeout`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html).  Other times, you might use ...

Context matters.  What makes the most sense in **your** situation?

Comment: That's a good point. Let me give more specific information on the context. Basically, when the job runs, it launches a few processes (1 for the crontab schedule, 1 for the .sh script, 1 for the JVM). I want all processes to end after the timeout. The easiest for me from a maintenance point of view is to set the timeout in the crontab directly. Since I am not sure on how the process hierarchy is handled in Ubuntu, I was afraid the JVM process would keep running and only the .sh script would be killed if I did that.

Comment: Go for the simplest solution and only upgrade when you need to.  Thus, I'd try `timeout` and see how it works.  If not, I might look into streamlining some details.  For example, what does your script do?  If it just sets up the environment then calls the JVM, you might consider `exec` so that the shellscript's PID becomes the JVM's PID.  At that point, `timeout` should do what you want.  If it's more convoluted than that, I might setup your timeout inside your shellscript, and kill all necessary processes.  In short, "try it, and see".

Comment: I think I will go with putting the timeout in the cronjob as such:
timeout 600 /bin/sh myscript.sh

And then in the script, I will call my java app as such:

exec sudo java -jar myjarfile.jar. Would that work?

Comment: It should, although I question why you need `sudo`.  If this script is running as root, why not use root's crontab?  There may be "yet another" process in the mix, vis-a-vis `sudo`.

Comment: Good point, I already scheduled the script using sudo crontab -e, so running the java app with sudo is redundant. I will remove it, thanks again for the tips!